# The diagram shows a mass being acted on by a number of forces. The system is in equilibrium.

Tags: vectors, physics

Diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3jY5.jpg

The question is to find $F_2$

As you can see in the photo, I tried taking the horizontal components of $F_2$ and the force with magnitude $3$.
I set $F_1$ as the sum of these forces then set $F_1=10$ because the system is in equilibrium and the other opposite force is $10$.
This gave an answer that does not match any of the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

In the vertical direction, we have $\dfrac{ F_2} {\sqrt {2}}-4-\dfrac32=0.$

Comment: you mean $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @SakethMalyala:  yes, thanks; I have corrected that typo.

Comment: Ahh, got it. So then $F_2=\frac{11\sqrt2}{2}$.

Comment: You got it!   Option B

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to consider vertical forces, that way you can ignore $F_1$, and if applicable, any error in such a calculation.

The total downward force is $3\sin(30)+4=5.5N$.

Therefore, the total vertical contribution from $F_2$ is $5.5N$.

Therefore, the magnitude of $F_2$ is $5.5\sqrt{2}$ N, or option B.